# Got an Error while Updating the Values in MONGODB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

"This is the user Schema and on Updating the verified property i got this error

Cast to string failed for value "{ email: 'test@gmail.com', otp: '6675' }" (type Object) at path "email" for model
"user"

i tried to find this error in my backend server but i got nothing which might cause this error so please help if anyone knows what this issue might be "

````
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema= new Schema({
    username:{ type: String, lowercase: true,index:true , trim: true ,unique:true,sparse:true},
    email:{type:String,unique:true},
    name:{type:String},
    // age: { type: Number, min: 18, max: 65},
    password:{type:String,require:true},
    verified:{type:Boolean,default:false}
    
})

const User =mongoose.model("user",UserSchema)



module.exports = User```
````

Comment: It seems you are settings `{ email: 'test@gmail.com', otp: '6675' }` as email value.

Comment: Can you show the error stack? Show the code that throws this error.